# JNI4Net, capturing java events from c#

Tags: java, c#, c++, java-native-interface

Where I work we are using jni, to be able to run in our application (implemented in c#) a graphical viewer that is implemented in Java. To do this we use JNI and it works correctly, the problem is that now we want to capture the events that occur in this Java viewer and launch a c# method when the event occurs. It is possible to do this with JNI. I've tried using RegisterNatives () but I can't get it to work.

The code that I found on the internet is for C++ and Open JDK, we use C# and Jdk1.8.

Example of code(From stackOverflow):

```
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
{"hashCode",    "()I",                    (void *)&JVM_IHashCode},
{"wait",        "(J)V",                   (void *)&JVM_MonitorWait},
{"notify",      "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotify},
{"notifyAll",   "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotifyAll},
{"clone",       "()Ljava/lang/Object;",   (void *)&JVM_Clone},
};


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
(*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls,
                        methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
}
```

Neither Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives, JNIEXPORT void JNICALL, nor the function pointer **(void *)&JVM_IHashCode** does not work as they do not know what functions are called in jdk1.8

Does anyone know if there's any way to get this?

Comment: Do you have access to Java code.

Comment: Yes, the java code is implemented by me.

Comment: Have you considered replacing the viewer component with something in C# / .net? Or isn't this an option at all? To me it seems pretty odd and overly complex to go through all that hassle for just a viewer component.

Comment: The viewer uses a complete Java GIS API, so replacing it it's imposible.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** I completely didn't get your approach with registering natives, so maybe I understand you requirements wrong.

I see two options for you.

1. You can create java entry point

Here is example:

```
class MyEntryPoint {
    public static List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void fire() {
        list.forEach(Runnable::run);
    }
    public void addListener(Runnable listener) {
        list.add(listener);
    }
}
```

Then you access from `.Net` to this static class via `JNI` and add listener. `Java` app notify about all useful event. You should replace `Runnable` with appropriate interface.

Most difficult part is implement interface in `C#`.

2. Create tcp server in your `Java` app and connect to it from `.Net`.